# Cannot set innerHTML on one, of two, identical functions

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have two functions that are essentially identical. The `negIndex` function works as advertised, no problems, but the `posIndex` function give me the error "cannot set enterTable.innerHTML to 'null'".

I'm fairly new to Javascript so it could be something obvious, but if it is i'm lost. I've tried a few different things without positive results. Any help would be appreciated.

The HTML

```
<ul id="exitTable" style="list-style-type: none; display: flex; flex-direction: column; vertical-align: center"></ul>
<br>
<ul id="enterTable" style="list-style-type: none; display: flex; flex-direction: column; vertical-align: center"></ul>
```

The Javascript

```
// Put DOM elements into variables
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');
const price = document.querySelector('#stockPrice');
const shares = document.querySelector('#sharesAmount');
const commission = document.querySelector('#commissionAmount');
const fee = document.querySelector('#feeAmount');
const max = document.querySelector('#maxGain');
const msg = document.querySelector('.msg');
const exitTable = document.querySelector('#exitTable');
const enterTable = document.querySelector('#enterTable');

// Listen for form submit
myForm.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);

function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (price.value === '' || shares.value === '') {
        // alert
        msg.classList.add('error');
        msg.innerHTML = 'Please enter required fields';

        // Remove error after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(() => msg.remove(), 3000);
    } else {
        let subTotal = price.value * shares.value;
        subTotal = subTotal.toFixed(2)
        let total = subTotal + parseFloat(commission.value);

        function popList(name) {
            let li = document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent = name;
            li.style.cssText = 'text-align: center'
            return li;
        }

        //finds the 5%-50% loss amounts based on subTotal
        function negIndex(num) {
            let negPer = -0.05;
            let negArray = [];
            let i = 0;
            exitTable.innerHTML = "";
            while (negPer >= -0.50) {
                negArray[i] = parseFloat(num * negPer).toFixed(2);
                let s = parseFloat(negPer * 100).toFixed(1) + "% " + negArray[i];
                let x = popList(s); //creating list elements
                exitTable.appendChild(x);
                i++;
                negPer += -0.05;
            }
        }

        function posIndex(num) {
            let posPer = 0.05;
            let posArray = [];
            let i = 0;
            enterTable.innerHTML = "";
            while (posPer <= 1.00) {
                posArray[i] = parseFloat(num * posPer).toFixed(2);
                let s = parseFloat(posPer * 100).toFixed(1) + "% ->" + posArray[i];
                let x = popList(s);
                enterTable.appendChild(x);
                i++;
                posPer += 0.05;
            }
        }

        posIndex(subTotal);
        negIndex(subTotal);
}

//Listen for form clear
myForm.addEventListener('reset', onReset);

function onReset() {
    price.innerHTML = "";
    shares.innerHTML = "";
    commission.innerHTML = "";
    fee.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but since you are a new contributor, I would like to say this: keep the posted code short so that others will be able to help you better.  Long code can make people leave your question without even reading it.  See [this SO help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `msg.remove()` removes the element from DOM, and I don’t see where you reattach the element to the DOM before you try to display it.

Comment: Your JavaScript contains some errors. onSubmit is never closed and subTotal seems to be declared inside onSubmit, but it will not be available outside that function. The html is not matching the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just gessing what your html could look like

```js
// Put DOM elements into variables
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');
const price = document.querySelector('#stockPrice');
const shares = document.querySelector('#sharesAmount');
const commission = document.querySelector('#commissionAmount');
const fee = document.querySelector('#feeAmount');
const max = document.querySelector('#maxGain');
const msg = document.querySelector('.msg');
const exitTable = document.querySelector('#exitTable');
const enterTable = document.querySelector('#enterTable');
let subTotal = 0;

// Listen for form submit
myForm.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);

function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (price.value === '' || shares.value === '') {
        // alert
        msg.classList.add('error');
        msg.innerHTML = 'Please enter required fields';

        // Remove error after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(() => {
            msg.classList.remove('error');
            msg.innerHTML = '';
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        subTotal = price.value * shares.value;
        subTotal = subTotal.toFixed(2)
    }

    posIndex(subTotal);
    negIndex(subTotal);
}

function popList(name) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = name;
    li.style.cssText = 'text-align: center'
    return li;
}

//finds the 5%-50% loss amounts based on subTotal
function negIndex(num) {
    let negPer = -0.05;
    let negArray = [];
    let i = 0;
    exitTable.innerHTML = "";
    while (negPer >= -0.50) {
        negArray[i] = parseFloat(num * negPer).toFixed(2);
        let s = parseFloat(negPer * 100).toFixed(1) + "% " + negArray[i];
        let x = popList(s); //creating list elements
        exitTable.appendChild(x);
        i++;
        negPer += -0.05;
    }
}

function posIndex(num) {
    let posPer = 0.05;
    let posArray = [];
    let i = 0;
    enterTable.innerHTML = "";
    while (posPer <= 1.00) {
        posArray[i] = parseFloat(num * posPer).toFixed(2);
        let s = parseFloat(posPer * 100).toFixed(1) + "% ->" + posArray[i];
        let x = popList(s);
        enterTable.appendChild(x);
        i++;
        posPer += 0.05;
    }
}

//Listen for form clear
myForm.addEventListener('reset', onReset);

function onReset() {
    price.innerHTML = "";
    shares.innerHTML = "";
    commission.innerHTML = "";
    fee.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
    <div>
        <label for="stockPrice">Stock price</label>
        <input type="number" id="stockPrice" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="sharesAmount">Shares amount</label>
        <input type="number" id="sharesAmount" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="commissionAmount">Commission amount</label>
        <input type="number" id="commissionAmount" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="feeAmount">Fee amount</label>
        <input type="number" id="feeAmount" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="maxGain">Max gain</label>
        <input type="number" id="maxGain" />
    </div>
    <div class="msg"></div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul id="exitTable" style="list-style-type: none; display: flex; flex-direction: column; vertical-align: middle"></ul>
<br>
<ul id="enterTable" style="list-style-type: none; display: flex; flex-direction: column; vertical-align: middle"></ul>
```

Comment: Essentially, yes that's what it looks like.

So you moved the neg/posIndex functions outside of the onSubmit, and called them from within. I see. That does the trick, and I appreciate your response.

I'm still kinda curious why, if I comment out the `posIndex` in my original code, and only run the negative it works, but both at the same time won't. I've even combined them into one function still within onSubmit, and it worked. Weird.